# Absolutely irreducible representations of affine group schemes of finite type over a field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an affine group scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$. Suppose that $V$ is a finite dimensional representation of $G$.

For every $k$-algebra $A$ we have the base change representation $V_A = V\otimes_kA$ of the group $G_A = \mathrm{Spec}\, A\times_{\mathrm{Spec}\,k}G$.

**Definition 1.** *$V$ is absolutely irreducible if for every $k$-algebra $A$ there are no nontrivial subspaces $W\nsubseteq V$ such that $W_A = A\otimes_kW$ is $G_A$-stable in $V_A$.*

**Definition 2.** *$V$ is absolutely irreducible if for every field extension $L$ of $k$ the representation $V_L$ of the group $G_L$ is irreducible.*

Two definitions above capture the same notion. Indeed, if $W_A$ is $G_A$-stable for some $k$-algebra $A$, then pick a nonzero morphism $A\rightarrow L$ into a field $L$ over $k$. Then $W_L$ is $G_L$-stable. So if there are no stable subspaces in the second sense, there are also no stable subspaces in the first. The other implication is trivial.

**Fact.**
*Suppose that $G$ is reduced. If $V$ is irreducible, then $V$ is absolutely irreducible.*

**Sketch of proof.**
Since $G$ is reduced and $k$ is algebraically closed, we deduce that $V$ is an irreducible representation of the abstract group $G(k)$. Suppose that the dimension of $V$ is $n$ and consider a morphism $\rho:G(k)\rightarrow \mathbb{M}_n(k)$ inducing action of $G(k)$ on $V$. Extend $\rho$ to a morphism of $k$-algebras $\tilde{\rho}:k[G(k)]\rightarrow  \mathbb{M}_n(k)$. By [Jacobson's density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_density_theorem) we derive that $\tilde{\rho}$ is surjective. This property is stable under base change. This implies that $V_L$ is irreducible over $G_L(L)$ and hence $V_L$ is irreducible over $G_L$.

Now my question:

> *Suppose that $G$ is nonreduced. If $V$ is irreducible, then is $V$ absolutely irreducible?*

Comment: Your definition does not make much sense to me: if $I$ is a proper ideal of $A$, then $V\otimes_kI$ is non-trivial $G_A$-stable submodule of $V\otimes_kA$. The standard definition assumes that $V\otimes_kA$ is irreducible for all field extensions $A$ of $k$; but the fact that every irreducible representation is absolutely irreducible is standard, since $k$ is algebraically closed

Comment: @Angelo The definition I wrote was incorrect and was not the one I had in mind. Thank you for your comment. Can you please provide reference for irreducible $\Rightarrow$ absolutely irreducible for every group scheme of finite type over $k$?

Comment: @JimHumphreys It seems that this answers my question. Can you provide reference or maybe write an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is an affine group scheme over an algebraically closed field $k$, and $V$ is a finite dimensional representation of $G$. Let $K$ be an extension of $k$, and assume that $V_K$ is reducible as a representation of $G_K$. Then I claim that $V$ is reducible as a representation of $G$.

Let $r$ be an integer with $0 < r < \dim V$, such that $V_K$ has a $G_K$-invariant $r$-dimensional sub-vector space. Let $\mathbb{G}(r,V)$ the Grassmannian of $r$-dimensional vector spaces of $V$, with its induced action of $G$. Since formation of scheme-theoretic fixed point loci commutes extension of base field, the fix point locus $\mathbb{G}(r,V)^G$ has a $K$-valued point. This means that is non-empty; since it is of finite type, and $k$ is algebraically closed, this means that $\mathbb{G}(r,V)^G$ has a $k$-valued point, so $V$ is reducible.

Comment: Thank you. One more question. Can the proof be generalized to arbitrary group functors on the category of $k$-algebras?

Comment: Slup: the problem with actions of arbitrary group functors is that the fixed points functor might be not representable.

Answer (score 2):

The classical viewpoint is captured well in the 1962 book *Representation Theory of Finite Groups and Associative Algebras* by Curtis and Reiner (Wiley), Corollary 29.15.    This of course doesn't directly answer the question about non-reduced representations of affine group schemes.   But I suspect this generalizes.   See for example II, $\S2$ of the 1970 book by Demazure and Gabriel, *Groupes Algebriques* (Masson, Paris).    This book is written in the language of affine group schemes.

(By the way, my comment on the question here was being edited when I was interrupted by a phone call and didn't finish the editing.)

Comment: @LSpice:  Yes, I've now deleted the comment.